# need to know variable for linear equation x and y for following

Tags: linear-algebra

Following is the quiz asked
solve system of equation given by
5x -2y = -13
4x +5y = -6
Options A)x= -3/7 ,y = 2/5
B)x = -7/3,y-2/3
C)x=-5/3 ,y=3/2
D) x =5/3,y=-3/5

how to solve this one..
to find the correct option

Comment: To check, replace $x$ and $y$ ...

Comment: Why even bother solving the system? You can quickly check all four of the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two equations $5x-2y=-13$ and $4x+5y=-6$ in two unknowns. therefore you can solve this.
If you multiply the first by 5, you get $25x-10y=-65$ and multiply the second by 2 you get $8x+10y=-12$.

ie

$25x-10y=-65$

$8x+10y=-12$.

Add them to get $33x=-77$, so $x=-7/3$.

Now plug into the first equation to get $5(-7/3)-2y=-13$ and rearrange to get $y=2/3$

Comment: I dont know how to mark your answer as correct... some one kindly help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  You could form a matrix $A$ such that $A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-13\\-6\end{pmatrix}$.

Then try inverting the matrix.  If $A^{-1}$ exists, $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}-13\\-6\end{pmatrix}$.